# Is it possible to call a subclasses' instance variable from its superclass in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

I've got a superclass Animal that is extended by Cat, Dog & Lion. These three all have a field `String sound` representing their sound. The method playSound(int i, String s) plays the sound s, i amount of times. Could it be possible to have a general method in the Animal superclass that takes in the field of the subclass calling it? Or do I have to make a separate, overriding method in each class that calls super with their own "sound" variable?

Comment: FWIW: You don't "call" variables, you "use" or "access" or "read from" or "write to" or "assign to" etc. You *call* functions/methods/constructors.

Answer (score 6):

The superclass can't access fields in the subclass. The usual approach here is to make an abstract getter:

```
protected abstract Sound getSound();

public void playSound(int times) {
    for(int i=0; i<times; i++) {
        getSound().play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The super has no access to the sub's fields, nor should it -- super classes should have no dependencies on their children -- but thanks to polymorphism, it doesn't need to. All you need to do is give super a `makeSound()` method, or something similar, and then have the sub's override the method, each playing its own sound.

re,

> Or do I have to make a separate, overriding method in each class that calls super with their own "sound" variable?

I don't understand what you mean by "that calls super...". You simply have the sub call its own sound within the `makeSound()` method override.

Comment: I meant that if I had a makeSound(int i, String s) method in Animal that had code that applies to everything, but changes output depending on s, in the subclasses should I just have another makeSound(int i, String s) method that calls super, passing it int i and their own sound variable?

Comment: @platelminto: you should have a makeSound method that does not take a String but rather that has its String supplied by the child classes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no, it's not possible. You can try making comparisons in the superclass like

```
if (this intanaceof of Cat)
play cat sound
```

But that would kind of defeat the purpose of polymorphism. I don't see why you would want to do it this way though. I'd do something like this:

```
abstract class Animal{

Sound [] sounds;
int soundI;

Animal(int soundI){
this.soundI = soundI
}

void playSound(){
sounds[i].play();
}

}

class Cat extends Animal{

Cat(){
super(5);
}

}
```

Comment: Bad idea to do the intanaceof, most of the times there's always a better way. In this case, the best solution is the abstract method.